# Datagrid databindings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a datagrid binded to a static ListCollectionView

CompassLogView class:

```
        public static ListCollectionView Compasscollection {
        get {
            if (_compasscollection == null) {
                _compasscollection =
                    new ListCollectionView(LogSession.CompassLogCollection);
            }
            return _compasscollection;
        }
        set { _compasscollection = value; }
    }
```

The Binding

```
compassLogDataGrid.DataContext = CompassLogView.Compasscollection;
```

the datagrid Xaml:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="compassLogDataGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Synchronizer.CurrentCompassLogDataItem}"
              Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=dataGridStyle}">
              ...
</DataGrid>
```

the `SelectedItem` (LINE 5) must be bound to `currentCompassLogDataItem` which is in `Synchronizer` class.

I have tried but it seems impossible. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="compassLogDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentCompassLogDataItem,Source={StaticResource synchronizer} }"
          Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=dataGridStyle}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <local:Synchronizer x:Key="synchronizer"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

local: specifies the namespace in xmlns.I hope this will help